# RecyclerView.Adapter and ImageView.getWidth()

Tags: android, imageview, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that display some element, in which may or not be a picture.
For displaying that picture, for performance reasons I'm using [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto) method.

I'm using it inside `public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final ViewHolder holder)`, but I still get 0 as width and height of my ImageView.

So, when should I display the image?

Comment: what do you need ImageView.getWidth() for?

Comment: To scale the bitmap I want to display . in the link I posted you can read the method

Comment: but what size would it have if you didn't set any Bitmap to display?

Comment: If I don't have a bitmap I don't call the method

Comment: maybe i missed the point: first you want to create a Bitmap so you can use it later in iv.setImageBitmap(), right? and you need iv.getWidth()/iv.getHeight(), but since you haven't called setImageBitmap yet iheight/width will be zero

Comment: mm the size of my Imageview is the size I set on my xml file, with or without the bitmap it doesn't matter. Or not?

Comment: and what's the size in xml?

Comment: w match_parent and h 200 dp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach a PreDrawListener on the ViewTreeObserver by doing something like `mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(...)`.

When that method gets called you can access the width or the height of the View.
Please remember to remove the listener once it gets fired: `mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this)` from your listener.

PS: sorry, I cannot access an IDE right now, so I may have done some typos ;)

Comment: is there a preferred place to add the listener? I still get 0 width and height.